# QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onValueChange"

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Sorry if this has already been asked, but I just couldn't find anything online.

I've been trying to emit a signal from a .cpp to my main.qml to change a text on a label, but I keep getting the error

> QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onValueChange"

when running the app. Also before this error started popping up, the text just wouldn't change. Here are the files.

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls
import LogicHandler 0.1
import "ui/LeftBar"
import "ui/MainTitle"
import "ui/CircleAnim"
import "ui/MathButtons"


Window {
    width: 1280
    height: 720

    LogicComp{
        id: logicClass
    }

    TextInput{
        id: textInput
        width: 40
        height: 20
    }

    //Equal button
    Button{
        id: equal
        width: 40
        height: 40
        onClicked: logicClass.callMe(textInput.text)
    }

    Text{
        id: label
        text: "Sample Text"

        Connections{
            target: logicClass
            onValueChange: label.text = OhmParallelOut
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QIcon>

#include <logic.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGuiApplication::setWindowIcon(QIcon("TMC.ico"));

    qmlRegisterType< logic > ( "LogicHandler", 0, 1, "LogicComp" );

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/TLCQuick/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

logic.h:

```
#ifndef LOGIC_H
#define LOGIC_H
#include <QObject>

class logic : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    float OhmParallelNum=0;
    explicit logic(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void ValueChange(float OhmParallelOut);

public slots:
    void callMe(float input);
};



#endif // LOGIC_H
```

logic.cpp:

```
#include "logic.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <string>

logic::logic(QObject *parent): QObject{parent}
{

}

void logic::callMe(float input)
{
    if (OhmParallelNum == 0){
        OhmParallelNum = input;
        qDebug() << "First entry. Currently: "<< OhmParallelNum;
    }
    else{
        OhmParallelNum = (input*OhmParallelNum)/(input+OhmParallelNum);
        Q_EMIT ValueChange(OhmParallelNum);
        qDebug() << "Adding. Currently: "<< OhmParallelNum;
    }
}
```

I tried changing the way callMe() interacted with logic.h and main.qml, so that hopefully the text would change into the value of OhmParallelValue, and although qDebug showed changes in the value, the text wouldn't update.

Comment: That looks rather complicated for a [mre]. You said the problem occurs when changing the text on a label, so why does your `Window` contain more than just the label? (Code in a question should focus on the question, not demonstrate "real" functionality/appearances.)

Comment: As an added bonus, as you reduce the amount of code, you're reducing the surface area the bug gets to hide in. The closer you get to the [mre], the more likely you are to reduce the noise around the bug enough to spot and fix the bug without help. Start the question-asking by making a [mre] and you're not all that likely to get to the question writing and posting phase.

Comment: The way you are using the `Connections` is deprecated. Please refer to the [`Connections`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-connections.html) documentation.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does it work if you make the first letter of your signal lower-case? `void valueChange(...);`

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been searching everywhere for a solution, and finally you gave me one that works! TYSM!

Answer (score 0):

Signals should start with a lower-case letter. I don't know of a technical reason for it, other than it standardizes the process of generating the `on-` handlers. (i.e. Qt autogenerates `onMySignal` when you define `mySignal`.)

There are other capitalization rules too. Enum names have to start with an uppercase letter, I believe.